# CMake could not find OpenGL in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, cmake

I want to install VTK in Ubuntu. CMake sends me this error :

> CMake Error at
>   /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108
>   (message):   Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY
>   OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR) Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315
>   (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
>   /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:161
>   (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
>   Rendering/OpenGL/CMakeLists.txt:196 (find_package)
>
> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but
>   they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set
>   and tested correctly in the CMake files: OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
>   used as include directory in directory
>   /home/pilou/Documents/src/VTK-6.2.0/Geovis/Core

I have hence installed freeglut3 and build-essential (as I have seen on Internet). But nothing has changed.

How could I find opengl to write my own link to CMake? What else could I do to install VTK?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**EDIT Following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47926071/4986615), we don't need to install freeglut (SDK for windows) but installing mesa is enough.**

You can install mesa an implementation of OpenGL. See indications in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47926071/4986615).

Therefore, if you have an error such that:

> Could NOT find OpenGL

Then, you want to install `libgl1-mesa-dev`. With debian-based system:

`sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev`

For an error, such that:

> Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: EGL)

Then, you want to install `libegl1-mesa-dev`. With debian-based system:

`sudo apt-get install libegl1-mesa-dev`

Comment: I am using a ubuntu server. But I cannot install it, like you described it. It says, that It cannot find te package.

Comment: Installation of completely irrelevant packages just to get their dependencies as a side effect is overkill (unless you actually want these packages). The way to go is to install the exact packages you need, see my answer to learn which.

Comment: Yes you are right. I update my answer to avoid misleading people

Comment: How can I install it without root? Not all users can install libraries. How can I install it with conda?

Comment: Quick suggestion if it still says that it can't find OpenGL: make sure you use the right capitalization. Ubuntu/Linux is case-sensitive. So, find_package(OpenGL) will work, but find_package(opengl) will fail.

I just got caught out by this myself. ;-)

Answer (score 20):

You don't need any version of GLUT to satisfy a dependency on OpenGL. What you need is OpenGL headers and libraries. In Ubuntu they are installed with the [`libgl1-mesa-dev` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/libgl1-mesa-dev).

To get the EGL build dependencies, replace the `gl1` part of package name with `egl1`.

Comment: how is this ment?
could u give me the exact steps pls?

Comment: I installed the packages but it's complaining about `-- Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY OpenGL)`

Comment: @SaeedMasoomi what if you install `libgl-dev`?

Comment: @Ruslan, The cmake file needs to have the path to the OpenGL libraries, which is named `FindOpenGL.cmake`, unless the library cannot be found(My Ubuntu version is 20.4) .  Everything is fine now, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

I have met the same problem, and however, none of the solutions proposed above helps me. In my case I found that there is no soft link for libGL.so, and so I just
go to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, and set up the soft link manually `ln -s libGL.so.1 libGL.so`. By the way, I meet the problem when I work on Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/) to make sure drivers are installed and available for access: