# CMake cannot find OpenGL Libraries

Tags: opengl, cmake

I am trying to install Mantaflow in my machine, but it says that it can not find libraries for OpenGL.

```
CMake Error at /home/ewunpyae/anaconda3/envs/ewp-project-env/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/ewunpyae/anaconda3/envs/ewp-project-env/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /home/ewunpyae/anaconda3/envs/ewp-project-env/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:433 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:667 (find_package)
```

I am running CMake on a new conda environment. Could anyone help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this help you? [CMake could not find OpenGL in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170869/cmake-could-not-find-opengl-in-ubuntu). If not, please provide more details. What exactly did you download?  Which command did you execute? Which OS? Which GPU? Do you have mesa installed?